# How to add in TextView new data(1 textView = 1 name), from Data Base? in a cycle

Tags: android, android-layout

I have tableLayout with 3 textView in a TableRow.
How to add  in TextView  new data(1 textView = 1 name), from Data Base?
 thats doesnt work:

my cursor say: select * from TABLE_NAME

```
  Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME,
    new String[] {"*"},
 null, null,null,null,"_id");  



    cursor.moveToFirst();
        try {
      if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
          return;
      }

      do {
          TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edit);
          textView.setText(cursor.getString(0));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  } finally {
     cursor.close();
  }
```

My table:

```
        _id student
         1   Said
         2   Bill
         3   John
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your `TextView` identified by `edit` each time you call `setText(String)`.  You may need to create new instances of `TextView` programatically.

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
do {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText(cursor.getString(0));
    row.addView(textView); //add each textview to your row
} while (cursor.moveToNext());

myTableLayout.addView(row); //add your row to your table
```

If you already have a `TableLayout`, you can add a `TableRow` to it using `addView(View v)`.  Add new instances of `TextView` to your `TableRow` and you should get what you want.